# Read data from callback url

Tags: javascript, php, callback, integration, httpwebresponse

I am working on integration project, when I request another system API's I will be getting the response to a callback URL which I defined.

I need to read the response, how to achieve this in javascript/PHP?

my call back URL is https://webhook.site/0c031a52-d9ee-4546-b85f-ca92857824f0

The sample response is below, I need to get the id from it

> { "requestId": "509900a5-392e-4d34-bcfe-90cc6bf3ad47", "territoryId":
>   "429defc8-5b05-4c3e-920d-enter code here0bb911a61345", "event":
>   "ordersChanged", "data": { "created": [ {
>   "id":"fb5e269b-9a16-4d44-abe5-a3f1c84acdb7", "geocodeStatus": {
>   "delivery":"OK" } } ], "updated": [], "deleted": [] } }

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Try parsing the JSON and then accessing the appropriate nested property.

Comment: Hi @CertainPerformance Can you please explain, how to parse json in php

Comment: Your question has only the Javascript language tagged, in which case you would use `JSON.parse`?

Comment: HI @CertainPerformance thanks for the reply, can you let me know how to parse JSON data from callback URL in javascript